# Namespace 'App' not found in default blank app

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I just started a new project using Xamarin.forms with Visual Studio 2017 for Android and iOS. I selected 'blank' and '.net standard' and when it openned I got this error: in Android `MainActivity`, `LoadApplication(new App());` App is not found. What can I do ?

Here's an image:

[image: https://i.postimg.cc/L5VhCdcP/Capture.png]

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try to clean, restrt visual studio and then rebuild the solution?

Comment: I removed my first solution and updated all SDK and android stuff, then made a new solution but same issue

Comment: make sure your Common Project (.Net Standard Project) properly referenced to Android Project.

Comment: it says the referenced component is not found

Comment: the referenced project ".....csproj" does not exist

Answer (score 1):

If a name contains spaces, directories will be made with spaces but VS will replace them by _.

Solution is to avoid ' ' and replace it by '_' or only one word.

Comment: This was my problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have faced this issue so many times that I have written the steps down:

- After creating a new project first clean build everything.
- Check the `AppDelegate` and `MainActivity` if they have any red lines(by that I mean unfound references)
- If there are(unfound references) restart VS if not continue.
- Now update the `Xamarin.Forms` package to the desired version.
- Update the Android Support libraries to the max supported version for that version of `Xamarin.Forms`, you "might" face issues here which you can pretty much solve with James's Blog [here](https://montemagno.com/resolving-android-support-library-nuget-installation-issues/).
- If everything goes well and you reach to this point remove the bin and obj folders for all your projects and since you have updated Xamarin.Forms VS will prompt for a restart with a `SnackBar` type popup on the top below the toolbar, restart the vs.
- Once restarted you would want to build the `.Net Standard/PCL` project first, And once this builds correctly try building the other two projects and it should work

Good luck

Revert in case of queries.

Comment: Thank you but my error was due to another mistake, I've made the answer so people think about it too

Comment: @MathieuGasciolli So you found an answer to this i guess?

Comment: Yes my solution name had spaces which made linking errors… thanks anyway

Comment: Oh Okay with what you posted it would have been impossible for us to know